# Emergence of Cauchy Principal value

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, improper-integrals, cauchy-principal-value

I have a problem solving differential equation, where I think there should be a Cauchy Principal value involved, but I do not see how it it should emerge. Let's say we have a differential equation:

$$
\mathrm{i} \dot{C}_1(t)=\int \limits_0^{\infty} d \omega \,  \nu(\omega)   e^{\mathrm{i}(\omega_{10}-\omega)t}, 
$$
where all the variables are real and positive. If we now solve the differential equation, it needs only to carry out the time integral

$$
\mathrm{i} C_1(t)=\int dt\int \limits_0^{\infty} d \omega \,  \nu(\omega)   e^{\mathrm{i}(\omega_{10}-\omega)t}=\int \limits_0^{\infty} d \omega \,  \frac{\nu(\omega)}{\mathrm{i}(\omega_{10}-\omega)}   e^{\mathrm{i}(\omega_{10}-\omega)t}.
$$
So the problem is that if the last integral is not taken as principal value, it will give $\infty$, so I would rather need it to be
$$
\mathcal{P}\int \limits_0^{\infty} d \omega \,  \frac{\nu(\omega)}{\mathrm{i}(\omega_{10}-\omega)}   e^{\mathrm{i}(\omega_{10}-\omega)t},
$$
where $\mathcal{P}$ is the principal value.
Would anyone have any idea where the principal value would emerge from, if at all? I was thinking maybe it has something to do when swapping the order of integrals in order to carry out the time integral first, but I am not sure.

Comment: It is not necessarily the case that the integral diverges. I assume you believe the Cauchy principal value is necessary because of the denominator $\omega_{10}-\omega,$ but if we suppose that $\lim_{\omega\to\omega_{10}}\nu(\omega_{10})=0,$ then the integrand has a removable singularity at $\omega_{10},$ rather than an unbounded singularity. Also, where does your differential equation come from? What is $\omega_{10}$? What is the domain of $C_1$ as a function, and where does the integral on the right-hand side converge? You said every variable is real and positive, but it is unclear which...

Comment: ...symbols actually represent variables here. Also, would it not be easier to use real numbers to actually talk about the integral here? Why not just say that $$C_1(t)=\int_0^{\infty}\nu(\omega)\cos[(\omega_{10}-\omega)t]\,\mathrm{d}\omega$$ instead? Do you have any boundary conditions on your problem for $C_1$? Because I believe you cannot simply antidifferentiate in the way that you did. In particular, what you are postulating is the existence of some function $$C_1(t)=\int_0^{\infty}g(\nu,\omega_{10},\omega)\,\mathrm{d}\omega,$$ such...

Comment: ...that $$C_1'(t)=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\int_0^{\infty}g(\nu,\omega_{10},\omega)\,\mathrm{d}\omega,$$ and assuming uniform convergence of the integral, implying that $$C_1'(t)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\partial}{\partial{t}}g(\nu,\omega_{10},\omega)\,\mathrm{d}\omega$$ with $$\frac{\partial}{\partial{t}}g(\nu,\omega_{10},\omega)=\nu(\omega)\cos[(\omega_{10}-\omega)t].$$ Somehow, I think you have missed something in all of this, but I would not know because I do not know how you are justifying your symbolic manipulations and I do not know the context by which this problem came about anyway

Comment: @Angel Thanks for the comment! The equation comes from 2-level system interaction with semiclassical light with perturbation theory. $\nu(\omega)$ here represents the strength of EM field, $\omega_{10}$ is the transition frequency of the 2-level system, which is the only fixed parameter, others are variables. I did not describe it because I thought mathematically it should not be relevant. Also, replying to your question if $\nu(\omega_{10})$ is 0, in general it is not, this is why I want to include the principal value. The boundary condition is $C_1(0)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your observation is precisely that Fubini does not apply, because one of the iterated integrals is (sometimes) infinity. But you can cut off a small ball around $\newcommand{\o}{\omega_{10}}\o>0$ before interchanging the integrals:
\begin{align}
 \int_0^t \int_0^\infty v(\omega)e^{i(\o-\omega)t}d\omega dt
&= \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_0^t\int_{\omega\in[0,\infty),|\omega-\o|>\epsilon} v(\omega)e^{i(\o-\omega)t}d\omega dt
\\
&= \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{\omega\in[0,\infty),|\omega-\o|>\epsilon} \int_0^tv(\omega)e^{i(\o-\omega)t}d\omega dt
\\
&= \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{\omega\in[0,\infty),|\omega-\o|>\epsilon} \frac{v(\omega)e^{i(\o-\omega)t}}{i(\o-\omega)}d\omega 
\\&=:\mathcal P\!\!\!\int_0^\infty \frac{v(\omega)e^{i(\o-\omega)t}}{i(\o-\omega)}d\omega
\end{align}
The above works only when $\o\neq 0$.
Also, if $v(\o)=0$ and is $C^1$ then the above still works but then the integral does exist, so $\mathcal P\!\!\int_0^\infty=\int_0^\infty$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I am not familiar with your notation, but as far as I understand from the context, is that we have a limit coming from the left and right around $\omega_{10}$, as one would usually define principal value. This is right now the same thing I tried to do myself, to artificially introduce the limit. My question would be - are we allowed to just introduce the principal value artificially? It is more a question of formality of mathematics.

Comment: @AndrisErglis If I understood correctly, then yes. It’s because before you need the principal value, you always have the freedom to write $\int=\mathcal P\!\!\int$. But only after you introduce it can you justify exchanging the integrals. Does that answer your query?

Comment: Also, for the notation, you guessed correctly, 
$\int_{\omega\in[0,\infty), |\omega-\omega_{10}|>\epsilon}$ means $\int_0^{\omega_{10}-\epsilon} + \int_{\omega_{10}+\epsilon}^\infty$

Comment: Good, thank you!